# Javascript: align parallel arrays index avoiding overlaps

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a list of arrays where the same item may appear in different lists (but not in the same list).
I'm trying to sort the arrays so that *matching items have the same index in all the arrays*.
I'm also trying to fill the empty spots where possible, but it's fine if some positions remain undefined.

**What it's for**

This is to manage the UI of daily events in a calendar.
In my case `myWrapper` is a **week**, where each position is a **day**. Each array inside is a list of **events** that can occour that day. Since an event could span more than one day (let's assume a simple case where a fullday event is 2 days long), we need that event to appear in the same position, in order to be rendered in a contiguous way with the day before.
Although it's not really visible, it becomes a placeholder and the block from the previous day will be twice as long.

**Conditions**

1. All dupes are always sequential, so if an element is a dupe, there's for sure a copy in the previous array.
2. Each item can occur only once per array (the dupes are only in different arrays)
3. The *foo* arrays may have different lenghts
4. The *foo* array always exist, in the worst case it's empty.
5. The order in the *foo* array is not relevant as long as the goal is accomplished.
6. The wrapper array can't be sorted.

**Input**

```js
const myWrapper [
    { foo: [] },
    { foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] },
    { foo: ['X', 'A', 'E', 'C'] },
    { foo: ['X', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'H'] },
    { foo: ['C'] }
];
```

**Desired output**

```js
const myWrapper [
    { foo: [] },
    { foo: ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'] },
    { foo: ['X', 'A', 'C', 'E'] },
    { foo: ['X', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'H'] },
    { foo: [undefined, undefined, 'C'] }
];
```

Is there a neat way to achieve this?

My attempt, sorting from the right and using a tmp variable to swap the items.
This doesn't seem to work well as the following position sometimes move previous items messing with the order set in the previous iteration.

```js
    let tmp;
    myWrapper.forEach((item, wrapperIndex) => {
        item.foo.forEach((currentFoo, fooIndex) => {
             // Search for match in the previous foo
             if(myWrapper[wrapperIndex - 1]) {
                const prevFoo = myWrapper[wrapperIndex - 1].foo;
                const prevIndex = prevFoo.indexOf(item);
                if (prevIndex >= 0 && prevIndex !== fooIndex) {
                    tmp = prevFoo[fooIndex];
                    prevFoo[fooIndex] = prevEvents[prevIndex];
                    prevFoo[prevIndex] = tmp;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Edit: the issue is also that the loop does other operations on the single items (which are objects really, I used strings to simplify), so I can't move from the right (current items).

> The output is rendered via Angular using 2 nested *ngFor so the final result has to maintain this array structure.

Comment: Can you describe the desired output? It doesn't look very sorted for me.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it's sorted because the same letters have the same index in the arrays

Comment: But why isnt the 'X' in the end ? Could the first array also be `[ 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B']` ?

Comment: Sorting doesn't mean that same elements have same indexes but that you apply a comparison function. Your result is not sorted. `{ foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] }` is lexicographically ordered. Why do you change it?

Comment: Arguably sorting is simply arranging by a specific logic, so it is sorted.

Comment: @Isac Because the letters are just to simplify, each item is an object. The sorting of each array is not relevant, it's just important that items have the same index.

Comment: are you taking the longest array as reference? or the last array?

Comment: @pilchard Yes, arranging by a specific logic and in my first comment I asked for the logic.

Comment: values shared between arrays should share index

Comment: @pilchard exactly. There's not a reference array, the only important thing is that shared values also share the index

Comment: Can't you sort each array lexicographically and add placeholders?

Comment: @ThomasSablik let's say that I can order Lexicographically (since they're really objects, I can sort by id for example), how would you propose to add the placeholders?

Comment: What are you doing with the desired output exactly ? I think it might be easier to transform these arrays into Maps or Objects, and have their unique identifier as key.

Comment: @Isac the desired output is rendered in the HTML with Angular (2 nested *ngFor), it needs to be arrays.

Comment: Let's start with a smaller example. `[['A', 'X', 'B'], ['Z', 'A', 'X']]`. The result would be `[['A', 'B', 'X'], ['A', undefined, 'X', 'Z']]`

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes, I think that would work fine.

Comment: Do each index in each array have unique values, or what would happen if there are four `C`s in total? Like if the second one got `'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'C'`.

Comment: @RickardElimää Give me a sec, I'll adjust the example

Comment: @Sampgun I updated my comment. :)

Comment: @RickardElimää oh ok...no, values are unique in the array, because they're really objects with an ID, so the ID can't appear twice in the same array

Comment: Isn't the input missing the last object?

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes, sorry

Comment: _the index of a value must be the same for all arrays in which it appears._  Accurate constraint?  And you want to satisfy this constraint by reordering the elements of each array, and adding undefined elements as necessary?  Any additional constraints?

Comment: @Wyck yes correct, no other constraints!

Comment: To me, the fun part of this would be to additionally _minimize the number of additional undefined elements required_.  But since you didn't ask for that, I'll leave it for another question.

Comment: Yeah I didn't ask because the way that the original arrays are sorted, leads to very few undefined elements. Anyway pilchard's answer does that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

A simpler solution using the same map of duplicates from my original answer but then using a simple swap algorithm to move duplicate values into their appropriate indexes.

```js
const myWrapper = [
  { foo: [] },
  { foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'A', 'E', 'C'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'H'] },
  { foo: ['C'] }
];

// find dupes and create map of indexes
let
  seen = new Set,
  dupeMap = {}, d = 0;
for (const { foo } of myWrapper) {
  for (const x of foo) {
    seen.has(x)
      ? dupeMap[x] ??= d++
      : seen.add(x);
  }
}

// swap duplicates into appropriate indexes
for (const { foo } of myWrapper) {
  let
    i, j, temp;
  for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    j = dupeMap[foo[i]];
    if (j !== undefined && j !== i) {
      temp = foo[i];
      foo[i] = foo[j];
      foo[j] = temp;
      i--;
    }
  }
}

myWrapper.forEach(({ foo }) => console.log(`{foo: [${foo.map(e => e ?? ' ').join(', ')}]}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**Original Answer**

Here's a fairly straightforward solution that avoids sorting. It first creates an object with props of duplicate values and expected index of that value in the final array as value.

It then iterates over each `foo` array placing duplicate values in a temporary array by index from the duplicate map, and pushing unique values to a second temp array.

before exiting, it tries to backfill holes in the temporary duplicate array from any values in the unique array.

This mutates the `myWrapper` array in place.

```js
const myWrapper = [
  { foo: [] },
  { foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'A', 'E', 'C'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'H'] },
  { foo: ['C'] }
];

// find dupes and create map of indexes
let
  seen = new Set,
  dupeMap = {}, d = 0;
for (const { foo } of myWrapper) {
  for (const x of foo) {
    seen.has(x)
      ? dupeMap[x] ??= d++
      : seen.add(x);
  }
}

for (const obj of myWrapper) {
  // collect elements into dupe/unique temp arrays
  const
    { foo } = obj,
    dTemp = [], uTemp = [];
  for (const e of foo) {
    (e in dupeMap)
      ? dTemp[dupeMap[e]] = e
      : uTemp.push(e);
  }

  // backfill empty indexes in dupe temp array
  for (const [i, d] of dTemp.entries()) {
    if (d === undefined && uTemp.length) {
      dTemp.splice(i, 1, uTemp.shift());
    }
  }

  // concat back into foo
  obj.foo = [...dTemp, ...uTemp];
}

myWrapper.forEach(({ foo }) => console.log(`{foo: [${foo.map(e => e ?? ' ').join(', ')}]}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Simply perfect...it works like charms. I'm also glad it fills the holes when possibile...this is really a treat! Thank you!

Comment: I think you deserve to know what this really was for: https://ibb.co/rFr9cnL

Comment: Edited with a simpler solution.

Comment: Very nice. I updated the code with the new changes. Looks also better! By the way I had to do some adjustments, because I couldn't use those new operators...
Anyway thanks again!!!

Comment: I made another refactor and now I have the definitive code :)
Check out my answer (although I'll keep yours selected, as it really led to the solution!)

Answer (score 1):

Your refactor relies on continuity of duplicates from one array to the next in order to maintain consistent indexing (because it's only looking behind one array). If you break this continuity, the indexing resets.

I copied your snippet and added a 'breaking' short array.

```js
function arrangeParallelItems(wrapper) {
  // start from the second element, so we're sure we can backlook
  wrapper.slice(1).forEach((item, itemIndex) => {
    let i = -1,
      dupeIndex,
      tmp;
    while (++i < item.foo.length) {
      if (!item.foo[i]) {
        // Skip empty values
        continue;
      }
      dupeIndex = wrapper[itemIndex].foo.indexOf(item.foo[i]);
      if (dupeIndex > -1 && dupeIndex !== i) {
        tmp = item.foo[i];
        item.foo[i] = item.foo[dupeIndex];
        item.foo[dupeIndex] = tmp;
        i--;
      }
    }
  });
}

const myWrapper = [
  { foo: [] },
  { foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] },
  { foo: ['H'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'A', 'E', 'C'] },
  { foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] },
  { foo: ['F', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'X'] },
  { foo: ['C'] }
];

arrangeParallelItems(myWrapper);

myWrapper.forEach(({ foo }) =>
  console.log(`{foo: [${foo.map(e => e ?? ' ').join(', ')}]}`)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ok I see what you mean. In my case, dupes are always from one array to the next. I edited the post to make all the conditions more clear.
Anyway it's good that this case is also covered!

Comment: No worries, glad you have it working for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with an even simpler solution starting from @pilchard's work.

**working with simple strings**

```js
function arrangeParallelItems(wrapper) {
  // start from the second element, so we're sure we can backlook
  wrapper.slice(1).forEach((item, itemIndex) => {
let i = -1,
  dupeIndex,
  tmp;
while (++i < item.foo.length) {
  if (!item.foo[i]) {
    // Skip empty values
    continue;
  }
  dupeIndex = wrapper[itemIndex].foo.indexOf(item.foo[i]);
  if (dupeIndex > -1 && dupeIndex !== i) {
    tmp = item.foo[i];
    item.foo[i] = item.foo[dupeIndex];
    item.foo[dupeIndex] = tmp;
    i--;
  }
}
  });
}

const myWrapper = [
  { foo: [] },
  { foo: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'A', 'E', 'C'] },
  { foo: ['X', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'H'] },
  { foo: ['C'] }
];

arrangeParallelItems(myWrapper);

myWrapper.forEach(({ foo }) =>
console.log(`{foo: [${foo.map(e => e ?? ' ').join(', ')}]}`)
)
```

**working with objects (the id here is the unique key to match the items)**

```js
function arrangeParallelItems(wrapper) {
    // start from the second element, so we're sure we can backlook
    wrapper.slice(1).forEach((item, itemIndex) => {
        let i = -1, dupeIndex, tmp;
        while (++i < item.foo.length) {
            if (!item.foo[i]) {
                // Skip empty values
                continue;
            }
            dupeIndex = wrapper[itemIndex].foo.findIndex((e) => e.id === item.foo[i].id);
            if (dupeIndex > -1 && dupeIndex !== i) {
                tmp = item.foo[i];
                item.foo[i] = item.foo[dupeIndex];
                item.foo[dupeIndex] = tmp;
                i--;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Blitz with more cases [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sort-parallel-arrays)

Comment: Looks clean, but unfortunately it breaks if you have an array in the sequence that has minimal or no duplicates.

Comment: why you say that? I'm using this very code and it works

Comment: I made a blitz with many cases, it works just fine!

Comment: just posted a simple breaking condition.